# How to determine the percent of missing values

Tags: r, dplyr

In a textbook of dplyr, I'm stuck with an exercise that:

> For each year in the ggplot2movies::movies data determine the percent
>   of movies with missing budgets.

I've tried code like this:

> ```
> movies %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(prop = sum(is.na(budget))/ n())
> ```

but the result is:

```
# A tibble: 113 × 2
    year  prop
   <int> <dbl>
1   1893     1
2   1894     1
3   1895     1
4   1896     1
5   1897     1
6   1898     1
7   1899     1
8   1900     1
9   1901     1
10  1902     1
# ... with 103 more rows
```

It seems that something went wrong. How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, it's just that none of the movies in those years (1893 through 1902) have budget data associated with them, so the percentage is 100% (1). Try sorting by descending year instead and you'll see regular percentages:

```
movies %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(prop = sum(is.na(budget))/ n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(year))
```

Results:

```
# A tibble: 113 x 2
    year      prop
   <int>     <dbl>
 1  2005 0.7048711
 2  2004 0.7655527
 3  2003 0.8271548
 4  2002 0.8344096
 5  2001 0.8486563
 6  2000 0.8779297
 7  1999 0.8723404
 8  1998 0.8674487
 9  1997 0.8769133
10  1996 0.8856115
# ... with 103 more rows
```

---

Also note that you can also compute this with `mean()`:  `summarise(prop = mean(is.na(budget)))`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I must be dizzy to ask such a question.